# How to use equation containing "]" in optional argument?

Tags: equations, optional-arguments

When I try to use a command like `\begin{theorem}[Something $x[y]$ something]`, I get an "extra `}` or forgotten `$` error message". It seems like the `]` in the equation is closing the optional argument even though the equation hasn't been ended!

What can I do about this?

Comment: `{$x[y]$}`  the braces hide the inner `[]`

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.